# .Net MVC C# - Reading file takes too long

Tags: c#, .net, deadlock

Occasionally our web service seems to stop.
All transactions can not be processed instantaneously and errors occur after tens of seconds.

Below is the Stactrace when the symptom occurs.

```
   Position: Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   Position: Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SafeCreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   Position: Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CreateFile(String lpFileName, Int32 dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttrs, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, Int32 dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile)
   Position: System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   Position: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   Position: System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   Position: System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   Position: System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   Position: System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   Position: System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   Position: System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
```

The occurrence cycle is not constant and occurs in days or weeks.
We serve the same .Net Web Application on multiple web servers.
When this error occurs, only one web server will fail.
It will be normalized automatically after about 1 minute.
At this time, the IIS AppPool is alive, and the logs of the AppPool are not checked.

I want to know why this error occurs.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402436/deadlock-at-microsoft-win32-win32native-createfile) we are asking a very similar question, although the environment is different.

[image: Request Current]

[image: Disk Queue Length]

Comment: In XDocument.Load, the destination file path is an XML file on the local disk.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]? With this little amount of information, it's almost impossible to come up with a decent answer. Chances are that either the file you're reading is (too) busy at the time, the system can't handle the IO, there's a spike in resource usage or you're encountering some kind of dead-lock.

Comment: Also, what is the exception message you get, Stacktrace is only one part and in this case most likely only shows clientside, not server side which is where I would look for any exceptions or locking/load issues.

I assume from the stacktrace its an URL, Could you change to download with a WebClient and then load from the response, that way you probably will get more information on whats really going on and could possibly retry.

Comment: A typical error message is shown below.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The connection timeout has expired. The timeout has elapsed while trying to use the pre-login handshake confirmation. This may be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server could not respond in time. The time taken to attempt to connect to this server is [Pre-login] Initialization = 30868, Handshake = 27. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Wait operation timed out

Comment: Database ConnectionString It takes tens of seconds for Win32Native.CreateFile to read an XML file as an XDocument object, as well as to read a local file with a StreamReader.

Comment: Web traffic does not increase.

Comment: @user3405759, Are you by chance using `XMLSerializer`

Comment: This is not the only problem with XDocument.Load.
It takes tens of seconds for Win32Native.CreateFile to read a text file with firestream as shown below.

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
{
 result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience to ask you via Google translation.
Thank you for your response.